# Use DKIM with SMTP TELNET CONNECTION

Tags: smtp, telnet, dkim

is there any why to use DKIM authentification with telnet smtp connection using these commands : 
Ehlo
Mail From
Rcpt-To
Data
QUIT

Let's say that i have already the private and public key generated:

The private key stored in a file in my server and the public key is propagated with my domain DNS.

How i can tell to SMTP remote server (eg gmail or hotmail..) that i want to use DKIM using telnet only?

Comment: dkim is not hyphenated

Answer (score 1):

DKIM is something you have to do yourself *BEFORE* connecting to an SMTP server. There are no SMTP commands to DKIM sign a message for you.

Comment: Hello , yes i get it , now i tried to form the signature , every thing is clear but the "b=" parameter i didin't find a way to compose it , any advice?

Comment: Read the spec and implement it? I don't know what else to tell you. I had no problems implementing it...

Comment: See my answer to your other DKIM question and upvote my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615230/how-to-calculate-b-parameter-in-dkim-signature