# How to calculate 'b' parameter in DKIM SIGNATURE

Tags: smtp, rsa, dkim

I'am trying to sign a message sent with SMTP commands (using telnet) with DKIM protocole , i applied in the official dkim website all the steps , it remains how i can calculate the 'b' parameter , should i validate it with the private key ? Or using another method?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in this document: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6376.txt

First, you must canonicalize the header fields that you wish to sign including the `DKIM-Signature` header that you are about to generate and then you sign it using the signature algorithm you've chosen.

### The "simple" Header Canonicalization Algorithm

The "simple" header canonicalization algorithm does not change header
fields in any way.  Header fields MUST be presented to the signing or
verification algorithm exactly as they are in the message being
signed or verified.  In particular, header field names MUST NOT be
case folded and whitespace MUST NOT be changed.

### The "relaxed" Header Canonicalization Algorithm

The "relaxed" header canonicalization algorithm MUST apply the
following steps in order:

- Convert all header field names (not the header field values) to
  lowercase.  For example, convert "SUBJect: AbC" to "subject: AbC".
- Unfold all header field continuation lines as described in
  [RFC5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt); in particular, lines with terminators embedded in
  continued header field values (that is, CRLF sequences followed by
  WSP) MUST be interpreted without the CRLF.  Implementations MUST
  NOT remove the CRLF at the end of the header field value.
- Convert all sequences of one or more WSP characters to a single SP
  character.  WSP characters here include those before and after a
  line folding boundary.
- Delete all WSP characters at the end of each unfolded header field
  value.
- Delete any WSP characters remaining before and after the colon
  separating the header field name from the header field value.  The
  colon separator MUST be retained.

### Canonicalizing the DKIM-Signature header

Once you've canonicalized all of the other headers that you wish to sign, you then need to apply the same canonicalization to the DKIM-Signature that you are in the process of generating.

Obviously, at this point you will not have the `b=` value yet because the result of signing the canonicalized headers is the value for the `b=` tag.

What you need to do is to construct the header but leave the `b=` tag empty.

For example:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=example.net; s=brisbane;
  c=simple; q=dns/txt; i=@eng.example.net;
  t=1117574938; x=1118006938;
  h=from:to:subject:date;
  bh=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTI=;
  b=
```

### Signing the canonicalized headers

Once you've canonicalized all of the headers you want to sign (plus the portion of the DKIM-Signature header that you are generating), you need to sign the result using the algorithm and the private key (not public key!!) and then base64 encode the result and append it to the DKIM-Signature header you've generated.

In the above example, you would use the RSA-SHA256 algorithm.

**Update:**

If the original message headers that you want to sign look like this:

```
Subject: ddddd
From: btt@domain.com
To: email@gmail.com
```

And if the DKIM-Signature header that PowerMTA generates looks like this:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domain.com; h=Subject:From:To; i=btt@domain.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=j/jYKloUFEbmzj5JdwmR7MCBB+UtuJq5V0wImYElaY/xob8CnRY39Z0TfPonp4y2qtIE/wpqwnT0
 YrHcNM8BY3uQ3ovm3pq7lTmwvM6XqA4rgnlhcyZnQO9uoUSGebsbR8KBhwZSpolF7UEcr8TSQdfO
 OG+fDZIHeq6G7DAg5cQ=
```

Then the text you *should* be signing would look like this (assuming you want your `b=` value to match the `b=` value that PowerMTA generates):

```
subject:ddddd
from:btt@domain.com
to:email@gmail.com
dkim-signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domain.com; h=Subject:From:To; i=btt@domain.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I take it you're not familiar with the IETF? They don't tend to move their documents. In any event, I've updated my answer. It was not necessary to downvote it.

Comment: Thank you , almost clear just one thing should i sign the header concatenated with DKIM-Signature like that : subject:HelloMarket
from:zlg59 <zlg59@domaine.com>
to:larysweng@gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domaine.com; h=Subject:From:To; i=zlg59\@domaine.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=

Comment: Yes, you sign the DKIM-Signature header that you are generating, the only thing you leave off is the base64-encoded `b` parameter *value*, but leave `b=` as part of the header. *Exactly* as you have it in your comment.

Comment: i compared the 'b=' value generated by PowerMTa and my script it's doesn't match , some thing wrong , can you see any issue on this content  :   subject:HelloMarket
from:zlg59 <zlg59@domaine.com>
to:larysweng@gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domaine.com; h=Subject:From:To; i=zlg59\@domaine.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=

Comment: I put in a txt file the content i sent you above , then i sign it using the private key with RSA-SHA1 , then i code to base64 , i compare the signature with the one generated by powermta , it doesn't match , i want just to be sure if the content is correct.

Comment: You need to lowercase the DKIM-Signature header field and remove the \ before the @

Comment: Update your question with the original (pre-canonicalized) headers of the message that you are signing and the post-canonicalized headers you are signing.

Comment: Also make sure that the line-endings for the resulting headers that you are signing are using the <CR><LF> sequence as opposed to <LF>.

Comment: This is the header original:
Subject: ddddd
From: btt@domain.com
To: email@gmail.com
------------------------------------
The canonicalaized header i sign combined with DKIM-Signature:
subject:ddddd
from:btt@domain.com
to:email@gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1;
a=rsa-sha1;
c=relaxed/relaxed;
s=selector1;
d=domain.com;
h=subject:from:to;
i=btt@domain.com
bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=;
b=

Comment: Post it in your question, not in a comment. I can't see where line breaks are when you post in a comment.

Comment: Why didn't you canonicalize the DKIM-Signature header like I told you to do?

Comment: I answered my post with the appropriate info , can you see it well now?

Answer (score 0):

Original Header :

```
Subject: ddddd
From: btt@domain.com
To: email@gmail.com
```

Canonicalized header with DKIM-SIGNATURE :

```
subject:ddddd
from:btt@domain.com
to:email@gmail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1;
a=rsa-sha1;
c=relaxed/relaxed;
s=selector1;
d=domain.com;
h=subject:from:to;
i=btt@domain.com;
bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=;
b=
```

RSA command to sign the content (header+Dkimsignature)

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign privateKey.pem content.txt | base64
```

Comment: Why didn't you lowercase the DKIM-Signature header field like I told you to do? Why did you line-wrap the DKIM-Signature header value? You should not do that.

Comment: I did (h=subject:from:to;)

Comment: Do you mean that i should lowercase this part "DKIM-Signature" ?

Comment: Yes, of course. That *is* what the spec says to do, isn't it?

Comment: The example you put in your explanation shows the DKIM-Signature not dkim-signature , no ?

Comment: Notice this comment above? `You need to lowercase the DKIM-Signature header field and remove the \ before the @ – jstedfast 11 hours ago`

Comment: Don't blame me for your incompetence. The spec says you need to lowercase the DKIM-Signature field name when you canonicalize it using the relaxed algorithm.

Comment: You also will need to remove the space after the `:` and stop adding a line-break after each `;`

Comment: Yes sorry , i guessed you mean the 'h' value . I did that but still not ok i didn't get the same signature like PowerMta, i will answer my post with the new content for clear vision.

Answer (score 0):

```
subject:ddddd
from:btt@domain.com
to:email@gmail.com
dkim-signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domain.com; h=subject:from:to; i=btt@domain.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=
```

Comment: Remove the space after the `:`

Comment: done but still not OK. Should i split the header and dkim-signature with "\r\n" also ?

Comment: Each line should end with `\r\n`, yes.

Comment: Yes, it looks ok to me now.

Comment: even the line of dkim-signature should end with "\r\n" after b=" ?

Comment: Yes. That line needs to end with `\r\n` also.

Comment: still not ok , i posted the difference between my signature and PMTA signature

Answer (score 0):

This is the new content to Sign :

```
subject:ddddd
from:btt@domain.com
to:email@gmail.com
dkim-signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domain.com; h=subject:from:to; i=btt@domain.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=
```

Comment: You still haven't removed the space after the `:` for the `dkim-signature` header. It should look like this: `dkim-signature:v=1; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly it doesn't match with signature generated by PowerMta.

'b' generated by my signature :

```
lNLa3tKsq6IEotwq6Go5vPUjj6zbzpIEqC7Mr90SZFrXPVBNZbHyO4igroLE5Ax77lAAAwEX9+cN
TCeIbzYE08K7kB7I4/k8McDe3T5V+T2jcZuR3ukWK12BkQBAmFZNogynId0tt1WPXK3zHDGdKpHC
oxu5gKfrEVNsHo7gyRc=
```

The header after a test with PowerMta :

```
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=selector1; d=domain.com; h=Subject:From:To; i=btt@domain.com; bh=rcr9nmkeqsjAGn29CUiUNJFRSmc=; b=j/jYKloUFEbmzj5JdwmR7MCBB+UtuJq5V0wImYElaY/xob8CnRY39Z0TfPonp4y2qtIE/wpqwnT0
   YrHcNM8BY3uQ3ovm3pq7lTmwvM6XqA4rgnlhcyZnQO9uoUSGebsbR8KBhwZSpolF7UEcr8TSQdfO
   OG+fDZIHeq6G7DAg5cQ=
Subject: ddddd
From: btt@domain.com
To: email@gmail.com
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. You didn't canonicalize the DKIM-Signature `h=` value correctly. In other words, it should not have been lowercased.

Comment: still no ok , this is the new signautre :Q7nW7tnzeGKapnpgDuW4xJS4sMmxL+bQChC4qjRWr+3pZ7CGtA25LHe9g8NBlNWAavRjKNvglQLO
VeuAXG/bimxCOe5mlwqEdoQjRAX0gCarmrRR0/jsLzJm+tRZWaPEuMaLBU7H71GqCykmUIUqqBgJ
WIEtD976Gj6xgcLsVgs=

Comment: Hello , it's ok just i have to remove the CRLF at the end of dkim-signature line.Thank you very much for your availability , i really appreciate your help